# int is 4 bytes but still it can be stored in char why is there no overflow

Tags: c

Check out this program

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main (){

char c='a';
printf("%d %d", sizeof(c),sizeof('a'));
}
```

the output is `1 4`
I know when we write a  statement char c='a';

then how does it happen that in space of 1 byte (char c) some thing of 4 bytes (ASCII code) is stored why is there no overflow etc.

Comment: Curiously, `sizeof('a')` is one of the differences between C and C++ (so the latter isn't a strict superset of the former): In C, `sizeof('a') == sizeof(int)`, in C++, `sizeof('a') == sizeof(char) == 1`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First, per ANSI/IEC 9899:1999(E) §6.4.4.4:

> 10. An integer character constant has type int. The value of an integer character constant
>   containing a single character that maps to a single-byte execution character is the
>   numerical value of the representation of the mapped character interpreted as an integer. [...]

§6.5.3.4:

> 2. The sizeof operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which may be an
>   expression or the parenthesized name of a type. The size is determined from the type of
>   the operand. [...]
>
> 3. When applied to an operand that has type char, unsigned char, or signed char,
>   (or a qualified version thereof) the result is 1. [...]

As you can see, since the type of a character constant is `int`, for `sizeof('a')` we get `sizeof(int)`, which is 4 on your platform. However, for `sizeof(c)`, we get the size of a `char`, which is defined to be 1.

So why can we assign `'a'` to a `char`?

§6.5.16.1:

> 2. In simple assignment (=), the value of the right operand is converted to the type of the assignment expression and replaces the value stored in the object designated by the left operand.

So, the `int` that is `'a'` is implicitly converted to a `char`. There's an example in there as well, showing explicitly that `int`s can be implicitly converted to `char`.

Comment: And if you want to be *really* pedantic, cite also 6.3.1.3/1, "if the value can be represented in the new type, it is unchanged", and 6.2.5/3, "`char` is large enough to store any member of the basic execution character set", and 5.2.1/3 "the basic execution character set shall have ... the 26 lowercase letters of the Latin alphabet" :-)

Answer (score 3):

The compiler implicitly converts the `int` to `char`.

```
int i = 42;
char c = i * 2 - 4;
```

That last line is interpreted by the compiler as:

```
char c = (char)(i * 2 - 4);
```

These [implicit type conversions](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/) are handled by the compiler - there's no "buffer overflow". The `(char)` is handled internally (by the machine itself, most likely, for simple types like `int`). It appropriately cuts down on the extra bytes and preserves the "signedness" (`+`/`-`).

Comment: What is meant by `preserves the "signedness (+/-)."` can you elaborate please

Comment: @AbhishekMane My guess is that I was referring to [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). For example, the binary representations of `-1` are different for `int` and `char`. Indeed, `(int)(-1) == 0b11111111111111111111111111111111`, whereas `(char)(-1) == 0b11111111`. C handles this for you, along with endianness (byte order). Admittedly, the conversion between negative integers is the same as for positive integers -- take the last byte for big-endian order.

Comment: what is `0b` in `0b11111111` ?

Answer (score 1):

"A character literal has type int" (http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v7v91/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.vacpp7l.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fclrc02ccon.htm)

But C lets you make theoretically "unsafe" automatic casts -- it's ok to for example,

```
char c = 34;
```

even though 34 is clearly a 4-byte int. What makes this safe is that you know when you write 'a' that it's really 1 ascii character and hence 1 byte.

Nice question by the way -- confused me for a bit.